# Functions and plots with dates in r

Tags: r

First time caller, longtime listener.

I am trying to solve two problems.

1. my function does not perform as anticipated.
2. I cannot figure out how to make a plot from date data

I have tried to approach my function problem from multiple angles but I am only making things harder than they need to be. The issue that I cannot overcome is that the date sequence I have created for the date range of the data set is not equal to the length of the data set columns.

For the y-axis of my plot, I want: 
f(dates[x])= number of data set entries on or before dates[x],
Where dates[x] refers to a given date in the data set date range

I'm sure there is an easy solution but I cannot figure it out.

Note: I used to have a basic understanding of r but I am relearning after a long break, please use the simplest terms possible

```
# import data
data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/washingtonpost/data-police-shootings/master/fatal-police-shootings-data.csv")
#
# coerce date column into date class

    data$date <- as.POSIXlt.date(data$date)
#
# sequence of dates for date range of data set

    dates <- seq(data$date[1], data$date[length(data$date)], by = "days")
#
# numeric vector for the number of days in the date range of data set

    xx <- c(1:length(dates))
#
# function meant to return a numeric vector of the count of entries in the data set that occurred on or before a given date
# within the data set date range. 

    fun <- function(x){

        sum(dates[x]<=data$date)
        }
        # This function returns a single value and not a vector as I'd expected. 

# This plot is the objective. x = number of days in data set date range, y = number of entries in data set on or before date(x)

    plot(xx,y=fun(xx))
```

Comment: `sum` always returns a single number. If there are multiple numbers, it adds them up. If you want to calculate the sum *for each date* you need a loop (explicit with `for` or hidden with something like `sapply`).

Comment: This would be a better question if you'd share a **minimal** sample of data (just 5-10 rows is plenty) and describe exactly what output you expect for that sample input. It's extra nice to share sample data in a copy/pasteable way, e.g., sharing code to create/simulate it or using `dput()` to share a small sample of actual data.

Comment: Thank you for the response and suggestion. I will include a brief summary of the data with the next question I ask. However, for this question, all I needed to hear was sapply and my mind-brain did a recall and I was able to create the vector I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: Anyone who is curious should be able to copy and paste the following into their r-box to see what I see

Comment: Yes, I appreciate that your example is currently reproducible because you gave a public link to a data set. But this still has the downsides of (a) it's not self-contained. If they ever take down the data, it's no longer reproducible. (b) If they change the data format, it's no longer reproducible. (c) It's not *minimal*. Questions are often easier to understand and easier to answer on a small example. Worth keeping in mind for your future questions.

Answer (score 1):

Working with dates is a loaded topic. It *is* extremely powerful, but it pays to be careful.   Here is my take:

```
data <- read.csv(paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/washingtonpost/",  # wrapped 
                         "data-police-shootings/master/fatal-police-shootings-data.csv"))
library(anytime)                   ## helper package
data$date <- anydate(data$date)    ## helper function not requiring format
```

Now we have a date type and you can do

```
data[ data$date <= anydate(20150110), ]
```

If you use the `date` on the x-axis it all works out correctly too.

That said, I tend to do all this inside of `data.table` objects, but that is more learning for you.  Another day :)   Keep it in mind -- the grouping aggregation and 
filtering are absolutely worth it.  And it is the fastest tool around.